# Как подключиться на C# к камере HIKVISION с помощью серийного номера?

Tags: c#, удалённое-управление

Как подключиться на C# к терминалу распознавания лиц HIKVISION с помощью серийного номера? например сайт hikconnect подключается к онлайн камерам через серийник. К локальным через IP адрес подключаюсь без проблем. Нужно подлючиться к удаленно расположенным терминалам.
Это нужно для обмена данными, забрать зарегистрированных пользователей, изменить базу данных например.

UPD: терминал стоит без компьютера, напрямую подключен к интернету. Статического IP нету возможности. Нужен способ напрямую подключиться к терминалу.

Comment: Может быть использовать VPN?

Answer (score 0):

К терминалу распознавания лиц HIKVISION с помощью серийного номера можно оказывается подключиться через сайт HikPartner Pro. Они выдают вам секретные ключи и у вас будет возможность напрямую через сайт управлять оборудованиями